# Many parameters passed to script in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, mv

I successfully passed one parameter to bash script in Rails:

```
par = @repository.repo_name
@result = %x[script/delete_repo.sh #{par}]
```

Now i need to pass 2 parameters into different script.
This solution doesn't work:

```
par1 = params[:repository][:repo_name1]
par2 = params[:repository][:repo_name2]
@result = %x[script/rename_repo.sh #{par1} #{par2}]
```

The script i want to use is:

```
#!/bin/sh
mv repositories/$1 repositories/$2
```

How to send more parameters to stored bash scripts in Rails ?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What sorts of values are in `par1` and `par2`? What do you expect to happen when `par1` is something like `'bobby tables'`? What do you expect the current working directory to be when you `%x[]`? How about inside the shell script?

Comment: I expect executing this script and rename my directory name. par1 - actual directory name, par2 - new directory name. The location is  "repositories/DIRECOTRY"

Answer (score 1):

```
par1 = params[:repository][:repo_name1]
par2 = params[:repository][:repo_name2]
@result = %x[script/rename_repo.sh #{par1} #{par2}]
```

If `par1` or `par2` can have embedded blanks you should embed them inside double or single quotes:

```
@result = %x[script/rename_repo.sh "#{par1}" "#{par2}"]
```

or:

```
@result = %x[script/rename_repo.sh '#{par1}' '#{par2}']
```

But, instead of creating a subshell, which happens when you use `%x` or backticks, use [FileUtils built-in ability to `mv`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mv) files:

```
require 'fileutils'
@result = FileUtils.mv(par1, par2)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about %x. but

```
`sh script/delete_repo.sh #{par1} #{par2}`
```

should work.

` - backtick

Comment: No unfortunately it doesn't work too. Nothing happened after executing this one. This script works good while executing from terminal. It doesn't from Rails controller.

Comment: Could you get the return value in a variable and print it(or log it) in the controller? Also try to execute this script from the rails console.

Comment: "mv: cannot stat `repositories/qX': No such file or directory "
It returns missing file. It is connected with second parameter of script.

Comment: So its a problem with your parameter. Are you sure the file exists?

Comment: It cannot exists. I want to use 'mv' to rename directory name. So this error shouldn't exists here than.

Comment: `%x` is the same as using back ticks. What works for one works for the other, and vice versa.